# Setting up Jupyterhub in ArgoCD doesnt accept values.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, jupyterhub, argocd

So I am new to k8s and helm and testing jupyterhub service. The issue I have is that I have followed the ArgoCD documentation but the values I want to change do not reflect in ARGOCD. Following is my set up.

I have a directory called `development/jupyterhub/application.yaml` and it contains the following:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: jupyterhub
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  project: default
  source:
    chart: jupyterhub
    repoURL: https://hub.jupyter.org/helm-chart
    targetRevision: 3.3.2
  destination:
    server: "https://kubernetes.default.svc"
    namespace: development
```

I also have a values file:

```
hub:
  image:
    name: quay.io/jupyterhub/k8s-hub
    tag: "3.3.2"
    pullPolicy:
    pullSecrets: []

singleuser:
  storage:
    type: dynamic
    extraLabels: {}
    extraVolumes: []
    extraVolumeMounts: []
    static:
      pvcName:
      subPath: "{username}"
    capacity: 12Gi
    homeMountPath: /home/jovyan
    dynamic:
      storageClass:
      pvcNameTemplate: claim-{username}{servername}
      volumeNameTemplate: volume-{username}{servername}
      storageAccessModes: [ReadWriteOnce]
```

The only change here is I have edited 10Gi to 12Gi but they don't take effect. I have also tried `argocd app set jupyterhub --values values.yaml` and tried passing directly as well.

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: jupyterhub
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  project: default
  source:
    chart: jupyterhub
    repoURL: https://hub.jupyter.org/helm-chart
    targetRevision: 3.3.2
  destination:
    server: "https://kubernetes.default.svc"
    namespace: development
    helm:
      values: |
        singleuser:
          storage:
            capacity: 12Gi
```

I started the service as follows

```
argocd app create jupyter --repo git@github.com:snap40/polaris-infra --path development/jupyterhub/ --directory-recurse --dest-server https://kubernetes.default.svc --dest-namespace development
```

note: I havent installed the helm chart , I am directly passing it to argocd.. also note jupyterhub service is running no issues there.